# Recyclerview Notifydatachange For only one item

Tags: android-recyclerview, refresh, notifydatasetchanged

I have a Recyclerview with a long list of items. One Item have a TextView, this TextView need change every 0.5 seconds, so i need refresh. All my code works perflecly but If I refresh all my items (notifyDataChange), its to slow. So I need refresh only this item for a good perfomance of my app. Its possible?

```
 AdaptadorRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `adapter.notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)`. You can mention the `TextView's` position and value with payload parameter. If you want to learn more about it please refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int, java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Thanks you!! And I add: " contenedor.setItemAnimator(null); " . Because i dont like the animation when it refresh.